# Heroku Add-on Edge CDN overwriting Content-Security-Policy header

Tags: heroku, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, content-security-policy, shopify-app

I am currently serving my Shopify App through Heroku.
Since Shopify apps are loaded inside an iframe in the merchants admin, one of the requirements is a correctly set `Content-Security-Policy` header. The `frame-ancestors` value has to be set to the stores url.

I added the Edge CDN to my Heroku instance to improve load times. The implementation seems to have worked fine.

But when I change my app URL to the new cloudfront URL, the App is not loading in the Shopify admin.

When checking the header, it shows

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';`

And the console shows:

`Refused to frame 'https://d247hdgomt4lwm.cloudfront.net/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".`

Loading it directly from the url, the same header would have been set to i.e.

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://better-bullets.myshopify.com https://admin.shopify.com https://*.spin.dev;`

Does anyone have an idea a) why the header is overwritten and b) how I would go about fixing this issue?

Thank you!

This is my Edge dashboard: [image]

This is the Edge CDN network request:[image]

And this is the default Heroku network request (this one is working fine):[image]